# Matrix filtering one time returns matrix and the other time just a vector

Tags: r, matrix, filtering

I'm having the following matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(data = c(0.2 , 0.1, 0.2 ,0.4 , 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5), nrow = 3, 
              ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(mat) <- c("x","y","z")
```

And I'm using this filter to filter its content according to columns `y` & `z` while at the same time I need only one row of it (whichever) and thus I'm taking the first one.

Once I use the 0.1 for `y` and 0.2 for `z`:

```
mat[ which( mat[,"y"] == 0.1 & mat[,"z"] == 0.2 ), ] [1,]
```

everything works as expected and returns :

```
  x   y   z 
0.2 0.1 0.2
```

From the other hand, If I use 0.3 for `y` and 0.5 for `z`

```
mat[ which( mat[,"y"] == 0.3 & mat[,"z"] == 0.5 ), ] [1,]
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error in mat[which(mat[, "y"] == 0.3 & mat[, "z"] == 0.5), ][1, ] : 
>         incorrect number of dimensions

This is probably due to the reason that the first filtering returns a matrix with two rows while the second one returns no matrix but instead just a vector (only one row has y=0.3 and z=0.5).

Is there any way to surpass this and be able to write some code without checking first if the return of filtering is either a matrix (so to use the [1,]) or just a vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to use `drop = FALSE` to avoid coercing to `vector`.  Checking the results of the subset,

```
submat <- mat[ which( mat[,"y"] == 0.3 & mat[,"z"] == 0.5 ), ]
is.matrix(submat)
#[1] FALSE

is.vector(submat)
#[1] TRUE
```

A `vector` doesn't have dimensions, that is the reason we get the error.  To avoid, this, make sure to use `drop = FALSE` for edge cases where there is only a single row returning (that causes to drop the dimensions)

```
mat[which( mat[,"y"] == 0.3 & mat[,"z"] == 0.5), , drop = FALSE][1,]
#   x   y   z 
#0.5 0.3 0.5
```